# jQuery .find() won't find <option> tag and acts quite weird

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am writing a webpage which includes a table, which could be filtered with the use of jQuery.
This sort of of filtering is possible with the use of a bootstrap 4 dropdown. To each option I specified a value:

```
<select id="inputState" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" name="sesso">
         <option class="dropdown-item" value="Tutti">Tutti</option>
         <option class="dropdown-item" value="Confezionati">Confezionati</option>   
 </select>
```

I have tried this super simple code written in jQuery, but it won't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var tipo = $("select").find("option").val;


if (tipo != 'Tutti'){

console.log($(this).find("option").val);
console.log('ciao');    
    
}else{
    
console.log('Addio');   
    
    
}

});
```

instead of printing what it is supposed to, it prints a bunch of code and istructions, this is the heading:

```
/! jQuery v3.2.1 -ajax,-ajax/jsonp,-ajax/load,-ajax/parseXML,-ajax/script,-ajax/var/location,-ajax/var/nonce,-ajax/var/rquery,-ajax/xhr,-manipulation/_evalUrl,-event/ajax,-effects,-effects/Tween,-effects/animatedSelector | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/license / !
```

Notice that the Web Page is PHP generated.

Comment: Thank You guys. I am a newbie, I excuse myself for my extremly dumb error.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery `val` is a method not a property so it needs to be `.val()`, not `.val`. Also, to read the selected value call `val()` on the `select` element directly, not on the collection of all available `option` elements. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tipo = $("select").val();  
  if (tipo != 'Tutti') {
    console.log('ciao');
  } else {
    console.log('Addio');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="inputState" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" name="sesso">
  <option class="dropdown-item" value="Tutti">Tutti</option>
  <option class="dropdown-item" value="Confezionati">Confezionati</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using val as property and it is a method.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var tipo = $("select").find("option").val();

if (tipo != 'Tutti'){

console.log($(this).find("option").val());
console.log('ciao');    
    
}else{
    
console.log('Addio');   
    
    
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="inputState" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" name="sesso">
         <option class="dropdown-item" value="Tutti">Tutti</option>
         <option class="dropdown-item" value="Confezionati">Confezionati</option>   
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are sufficient if you only need the selected `value` however if you do need to access the selected `<option>` directly and it's properties/attributes you can use the `filter(':selected')` method on the collection of matched elements.
Below I demonstrate accessing the data of the selected option, on page load and whenever the selected option changes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const $inputState = $('#inputState')

  $inputState.change(function() {
    // value of <select>
    let theValue = $(this).val()
    console.log("select value:", theValue)

    // first selected <option> element
    let $selectedOption = $(this).find('option').filter(':selected').first()
    console.log("option value:", $selectedOption.val())
    console.log("option data:", $selectedOption.data())
  })

  // trigger change on load
  $inputState.change()

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select id="inputState" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" name="sesso">
  <option class="dropdown-item" value="Tutti" data-option="14">Tutti</option>
  <option class="dropdown-item" value="Confezionati" selected data-option="option data">Confezionati</option>
</select>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```